# Why is one <div> refusing to show?

Tags: html

I have been working on a website: https://coronavirustest.co.nz/.

At a certain point in the form, I have a privacy disclaimer in the div `.privacy-disclaimer`, which (I *cannot* work out why) isn't showing up in the rendered page. There's no console errors and no warnings in VS Code.

The behaviour even exhibits in the snippet below, what am I doing wrong?

```html
<div class="subject-email-address mt-2">
            <label
              for="subject-email-address"
              class="font-bold text-gray-700 w-1/4"
              >Subject Email Address (for a copy of the test results)</label
            >
            <input
              type="email"
              name="subject-email-address"
              id="subject-email-address"
              class="border-b-2 w-full bg-gray-100 text-lg p-1"
              placeholder="john@example.com"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="privacy-disclaimer mt-2">
            <h3 class="font-bold">Privacy & Data Handling</h3>
            <p class="max-w-xl text-sm">
              Information is collected for the purpose of testing for COVID-19,
              and reporting positive tests to the Ministry of Health for further
              treatment. Information will be seen by the subject (person
              providing the test), the subject's employer, the tester (person
              conducting the test), the tester's employer, Sober Check Ltd
              (provider of the form), and the Ministry of Health (in the event
              of a positive test). Some information on this form is optional,
              the rest is required. If required information isn't provided, the
              test results will not be saved. All information collected will be
              handled in accordance with the Privacy Act 2020.
            </p>
            <div class="privacy-acceptance mt-1 text-lg p-1">
              <label for="privacy-disclaimer" class="border-b-2 cursor-pointer"
                >I'm happy to proceed</label
              >
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="privacy-disclaimer"
                id="privacy-disclaimer"
                required
                class="border-b-2 bg-gray-100 cursor-pointer"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Seems to be blocked by adblockers. I disabled uBO and the div shows up correctly. Also if I change the class to a random string it also shows up correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's blocked by my adblockers. Disabling it shows the div correctly, also with different class (the filter likely target the `privacy-disclaimer` and `privacy-acceptance`) they got through the adblockers. Do note that in the future someone might also add your new class to their blocking list.